# React table header width is changing when there is no data (after filtering)

Tags: react-table

I am working on a react-table that has sort and filter functionalities. When I filter and there is no data to be returned (empty table), the headers' widths are not staying fixed, they get reduced accordingly to the length of the header title. This is happening because when there is no data, tbody is completely empty, thus there are no cells that the headers can use for defining their widths.

You can see that in the schema when I am rendering each cell, I am assigning it a class. I use that class in the stylesheet to give the cells a specific width. I want all the cells to have a fixed width of 140px, and only the summary cell (task type) to have a fixed width of 360px. This works great for the cells, and when there is data the headers follow the cell widths.

See the picture (I had to cover the data due to privacy + I am showing only one row) - in reality, it has more. You can see in the picture that the header widths are matching the cells' widths.

[image]

Now, as soon as I filter the data out, and the filter input does not match any of the data, the headers get reduced to a width that depends on the length of the header titles. See picture:
[image]

The best comparison would be the following pictures of both headers placed on top of each other:

[image]

I tried many things: from using the useBlock/Absolute/FlexLayout Hooks to assigning the widths in the schema instead of via a CSS class, to playing around with CSS and trying out different options, but so far nothing works.

I would be thankful for any tips and suggestions.

Here is the code for the table UI:

```
const TaskManagerTable = (props) => {
    const {columns, data} = props;
    
    const {
        getTableProps,
        getTableBodyProps,
        headerGroups,
        rows,
        prepareRow
    } = useTable({
        columns,
        data,
    },
        useFilters,
        useSortBy,
    );


    return (
        <>
            <table className={CLASS_NAMES.TABLE}{...getTableProps()}>
            <thead className={CLASS_NAMES.TABLE_HEAD}>
                {headerGroups.map(headerGroup => {
                    const {key, ...restHeaderGroupProps} = headerGroup.getHeaderGroupProps()
                    return (
                        <tr className={CLASS_NAMES.HEADER_ROW} key={key} {...restHeaderGroupProps}>
                            {headerGroup.headers.map(column => {
                                const {key, ...restColumn} = column.getHeaderProps();
                                return (
                                    <th className={CLASS_NAMES.HEADER_CELL} key={key} {...restColumn}
                                        style={{
                                            cursor: column.canSort ? 'pointer' : 'auto',
                                        }}
                                    >
                                        {column.render('Header')}
                                        <span className={CLASS_NAMES.SORT} {...column.getHeaderProps(column.getSortByToggleProps())}>
                                            {column.isSorted ?
                                                <div className={CLASS_NAMES.ICON_SORTED}>
                                                    <SortIcon dir={column.isSortedDesc ? 'desc' : 'asc'} onClick={_.noop} />
                                                </div>
                                                : column.canSort
                                                    ? <div className={CLASS_NAMES.ICON_CAN_SORT}>
                                                        <SortIcon dir={column.isSortedDesc ? 'desc' : 'asc'} onClick={_.noop} />
                                                    </div> : ''
                                            }
                                        </span>
                                        <span className={CLASS_NAMES.FILTER}>
                                            {column.canFilter ? column.render('Filter') : null}
                                        </span>
                                    </th>
                                )
                            })}
                        </tr>
                    )
                })}
            </thead>
            <tbody {...getTableBodyProps}>
                {rows.map(row => {
                    prepareRow(row)
                    const {key, ...restRowProps} = row.getRowProps();
                    return (
                        <tr key={key} {...restRowProps}>
                            {row.cells.map(cell => {
                                const {key, ...restCellProps} = cell.getCellProps();
                                return (
                                    <td key={key} {...restCellProps}>
                                        {cell.render('Cell')}
                                    </td>
                                );
                            })}
                        </tr>
                    )
                })}
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </>
    )
};

TaskManagerTable.propTypes = {
    columns: PropTypes.array,
    data: PropTypes.array,
};

const mapDispatchToProps = {};

export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(TaskManagerTable);
```

Here is the schema:

```
export default [
    {
        Header: 'ID',
        accessor: 'key',
        Filter: ({ column }) => {
            return (
                <ReactTableFilter containerClassName={CLASS_NAMES.TASK_MANAGER_FILTER_CONTAINER}
                    column={column}
                    popoverInner={<FreeTextFilter handleChangeFilter={column.setFilter} filter={column.filterValue}/>}
                />
            )
        },
        Cell: ({row}) => {
            const key = _.get(row, 'original.key');
            return (
                <div className={CLASS_NAMES.ID_CELL}>
                    <a href={`some link goes here`} target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">{key}</a>
                </div>
            )
        }

    },
    {
        Header: 'Category',
        accessor: 'category',
        Filter: ({ column }) => {
            return (
                <ReactTableFilter containerClassName={CLASS_NAMES.TASK_MANAGER_FILTER_CONTAINER}
                    column={column}
                    popoverInner={<FreeTextFilter handleChangeFilter={column.setFilter} filter={column.filterValue}/>}
                />
            )
        },
        Cell: ({row}) => {
            const category = _.get(row, 'original.category');
            return (
                <div className={CLASS_NAMES.CATEGORY_CELL}>
                    {category}
                </div>
            )
        }
    },
    {
        Header: 'Subcategory',
        accessor: 'subCategory',
        Filter: ({ column }) => {
            return (
                <ReactTableFilter containerClassName={CLASS_NAMES.TASK_MANAGER_FILTER_CONTAINER}
                    column={column}
                    popoverInner={<FreeTextFilter handleChangeFilter={column.setFilter} filter={column.filterValue}/>}
                />
            )
        },
        Cell: ({row}) => {
            const subCategory = _.get(row, 'original.subCategory');
            return (
                <div className={CLASS_NAMES.SUBCATEGORY_CELL}>
                    {subCategory}
                </div>
            )
        }
    },
    {
        Header: 'Task Title',
        accessor: 'summary',    
        className: 'summary',
        Filter: ({ column }) => {
            return (
                <ReactTableFilter containerClassName={CLASS_NAMES.TASK_MANAGER_FILTER_CONTAINER}
                    column={column}
                    popoverInner={<FreeTextFilter handleChangeFilter={column.setFilter} filter={column.filterValue}/>}
                />
            )
        },
        Cell: ({row}) => {
            const summary = _.get(row, 'original.summary');
            return (
                <div className={CLASS_NAMES.SUMMARY_CELL}>
                    {summary}
                </div>
            )
        }
    },
    {
        Header: 'Priority',
        accessor: 'priority',
        Filter: ({ column }) => {
            return (
                <ReactTableFilter containerClassName={CLASS_NAMES.TASK_MANAGER_FILTER_CONTAINER}
                    column={column}
                    popoverInner={<FreeTextFilter handleChangeFilter={column.setFilter} filter={column.filterValue}/>}
                />
            )
        },
        Cell:  ({row}) => {
            const priority = _.get(row, 'original.priority');
            return (
                <div className={CLASS_NAMES.PRIORITY_CELL}>
                    {priority}
                </div>
            )
        }
    },
    {
        Header: 'Status',
        accessor: 'status',
        Filter: ({ column }) => {
            return (
                <ReactTableFilter containerClassName={CLASS_NAMES.TASK_MANAGER_FILTER_CONTAINER}
                    column={column}
                    popoverInner={<FreeTextFilter handleChangeFilter={column.setFilter} filter={column.filterValue}/>}
                />
            )
        },
        Cell: ({row}) => {
            const status = _.get(row, 'original.status');
            return (
                <div className={CLASS_NAMES.STATUS_CELL}>
                    {status}
                </div>
            )
        }
    },
    {
        Header: 'Task Type',
        accessor: 'type',
        Filter: ({ column }) => {
            return (
                <ReactTableFilter containerClassName={CLASS_NAMES.TASK_MANAGER_FILTER_CONTAINER}
                    column={column}
                    popoverInner={<FreeTextFilter handleChangeFilter={column.setFilter} filter={column.filterValue}/>}
                />
            )
        }
]
```

And finally here is the SCSS:

```
table {
  width: 100%;
  thead {
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
    background-color: white;
        tr {
            text-align: left;
            text-transform: uppercase;
            color: #91a4c3;
            font-weight: 400;
            font-size: 12px;
            th {
                padding-left: 10px;
                padding-bottom: 10px;
                .sort-container {
                    margin-left: 25px;
                    position: absolute;
                }
                .filter-container {
                margin-left: 30px;
                position: absolute;
                }
                .icon-can-sort, .filter-component-hide {
                  display: none;
                }
                .filter-component-show {
                  display: block;
                }
                &:hover {
                  .icon-can-sort, .filter-component-hide {
                    display: block;
                  }
                }
                @include relative();
                :nth-child(4) {
                    min-width: 360px;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    tbody {
        overflow-y: auto;
        @include scrollBar();
        tr {
          box-shadow: 0px 1px 5px 0 rgba(104, 105, 111, 0.09);
          height: 45px;
          color: #6a7097;
          text-transform: capitalize;
            td {
                padding-left: 10px;
            }
            .id-cell,
            .category-cell,
            .subcategory-cell,
            .priority-cell,
            .status-cell,
            .type-cell,
            {
                min-width: 140px;
            }
            .summary-cell {
                min-width: 360px;
            }
        } 
    }
}
```